# change composer.json for cake 3 stable

Tags: composer-php, cakephp-3.0

Now CakePHP 3 has stable version. How should I change my composer.json? I want to use only the stable updates for cake.

```
"require": {
  "php": ">=5.4.16",
  "cakephp/cakephp": "3.0.*-dev",
  "cakephp/migrations": "dev-master",
  "cakephp/plugin-installer": "*",
  "cakephp/bake": "dev-master",
  "mobiledetect/mobiledetectlib": "2.*",
  "phpunit/phpunit": "*"
},
"require-dev": {
  "d11wtq/boris": "1.0.*",
  "cakephp/debug_kit": "3.0.*-dev",
  "cakephp/bake": "dev-master"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the one in the official app repository:

https://github.com/cakephp/app/blob/master/composer.json

You may also want to replace the `ConsoleShell` as it got improved before the last release:

https://github.com/cakephp/app/blob/master/src/Shell/ConsoleShell.php

Answer (score 0):

You will need to update both the cakephp entry and the debug_kit entry, otherwise their dependencies remain stuck at cake3-dev. Doing it like this has worked for me (just showing the relevant entries):

"require": {
  "cakephp/cakephp": "~3.0"

},
"require-dev": {
  "cakephp/debug_kit": "~3.0"
}